# Correct way to have an endless wait

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a program that has a list of timers. Each of the timers has a tick event and lets just say for example, i have 10 timers started (all are in the List).

What is the best way to sit forever (or until i tell it to stop)? Should I just have a while loop?

```
foreach(Timer t in _timers)
{
   t.Start();
}

while(true)
{
   Application.DoEvents();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

I have a feeling that this isn't the best way...

-- Update
Here's my entire program:

```
public static void Main()
{
  // set some properties and set up the timers

    foreach(Timer t in _timers)
    {
       t.Start();
    }

    while(true)
    {
       Application.DoEvents();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Thats it. There is no UI, there's nothing else. If I don't have the while loop, then the program just finishes.

Comment: When does the program end in your current design?  Do you have some exit event behind one of those timers currently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `EventWaitHandle` or array of `EventWaitHandle`s to block thread execution by using the `WaitOne()` or `WaitAll()` methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kad9xah9.aspx

So for example

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
mre.WaitOne();
```

will wait for eternity.

**edit**

Since you're making a service, you might want to read [this article.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx)

Comment: this is what I'm going to end up doing. I'll need to rewrite some stuff to use the WaitHandler article that you referred me to.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By the `Application.DoEvents`, I assume you are on a UI thread here. It is never a good idea to keep the UI thread active (even with `DoEvents`). Why not just start the timers and release control back to the message pump. When the events tick it'll pick up the events.

Why do you want to loop?

---

Re the update; which `Timer` are you using? If you use `System.Timers.Timer` (with the `Elapsed` event) then it isn't bound to the message-loop (it fires on a separate thread): you can just hang the main thread, perhaps waiting on some exit condition:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        using (Timer timer = new Timer()) {
            timer.Interval = 2000;
            timer.Elapsed += delegate {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("tick");
            };
            timer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press [ret] to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for an, I think, better way to "hang the main thread".

Comment: The ReadLine was just an example - the important point was using the correct timer - i.e. not the winform timer with a "tick" event (which you mention in the question).

Comment: ahhh gotcha. Is there any way with a System.Timers.Timer to pass it a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could wait on a condition variable, or select() on a socket.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're exiting the program, you might consider using only nine timers and have the tenth activity part of the main thread of your code.

Each of those timers is a separate thread and should be handled carefully.

DoEvents is considered 'evil' and should be avoided.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx